# How to link the next button in virtual key board with Editext for validation in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my app i have five Edit-text field,after enter details in first text field using next button to go next edit text.before going next field i have to validate first edit text field clicking the next button in virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try with this code onEditorAction u can get enter click in virtual keyboard

     et.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
//if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL|| //event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)

      if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO ){
       // do something here
      }
      return false;
     }
```